# Can married Miis get divorced in Tomodachi Life?

Tags: tomodachi-life

In Tomodachi Life, is it possible for two married Miis to break up and get divorced?

For example, let’s say my Mii was married to the Mii of an ex-girlfriend. Would there be any way for me to end that relationship?

Answer (score 2):

Married Miis can get divorced, but you can't choose when.

When the relationship between the Miis gets rough (you can press L or R while talking to the mii to see the relationship), the Miis might get divorced.

Comment: Can you elaborate with more detail? What causes a divorce to happen? Is it random?

Comment: I edited the answer to include why a divorce might happen.